# How to break text lines into a Javascript confirm()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display to lines of text in a Javascript confirm() function:

1ST line: ¿DO YOU REALLY WANT TO CANCEL THE OPERATION?

2ND line: ALL ENTERED DATA WILL BE LOST');

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    return confirm('¿DO YOU REALLY WANT TO CANCEL THE OPERATION? ALL ENTERED DATA WILL BE LOST');
});​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8jEZZ/

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add `\n` and magic will happen!

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    return confirm('¿DO YOU REALLY WANT TO CANCEL THE OPERATION? \n ALL ENTERED DATA WILL BE LOST');
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

try newline character,working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcf9d/)

```
  $('#button').click(function () {
    return confirm('¿DO YOU REALLY WANT TO CANCEL THE OPERATION?\n ALL ENTERED DATA WILL BE LOST');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a newline character

```
$('#button').click(function () {
   return confirm('¿DO YOU REALLY WANT TO CANCEL THE OPERATION? \nALL ENTERED DATA WILL BE        LOST');
});​
```